# how to mock a protected method in an abstract class called from BaseClass

Tags: java, spring, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Updating the original question.

I will put the original code piece and then put in questions.

Class under test

package my.main.class.package;

```
public class MyClassHelper extends MySession {

//Session is an abstract class.

//the method that I want to test
public PrimaryKey myMethod() throws Exception {
try{
//this is a method of Session class
beginTransaction(TXN_NOT_TIMED);

//doSomething;
} catch(Exception e) {
//another method from abstract class.
rollback();
}
}
```

Code of abstract class Session. This class is added as dependency in my project, so its in jar file.

```
package my.class.some.other.package;

public abstract class MySession implements Session {
protected void beginTransaction(boolean timedTransaction) throws SessionException {
        this.getTransactionBeginWork((String)null, true, timedTransaction, false);
    }
}
```

**My issue:**

- I am not able to mock the part of beginTransaction() when writing unit test for MyClassHelper.  *Reason*: beginTransaction() is in another package and is protected and so not visible when trying to unit test MyClassHelper.

**Failed Solutions as inline comment.**
added a class in the same package structure of MySession:

```
package my.class.some.other.package

class MySessionTest {

@Mock private MySession session;

public void beginTransaction() throws SessionException {
doNothing().when(session).beginTransaction(anyBoolean());
}
}
```

Test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClassHelperTest {
private MySimpleSessionTest sessionTest = new MySimpleSessionTest();
@InjectMock private MyClassHelper myClassHelper;
@Mock MySession sessionMock;

@Test
public void myTest() {

//one way
sessionTest.beginTransaction();
//what happens here is eventhough I did doNothing() in //MySessionTest, it doesn't mock that method and instead execution //goes inside beginTransaction() of MySession class.

doNothing().when(sessionMock). //here I don't get the //beginTransaction() option after "."
myClassHelper.myMethod();
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Refactor your code so that `MyClassHelper` doesn't extend anything, and has an instance of `MySession` as a field, passed to the `MyClassHelper` constructor. You can mock this instance.

Comment: It's kind of legacy code, and a change would require a lot of testing as per the process. That's why I am looking for a way to mock it. I am not sure why the helper test MySessionTest is not able to mock MySession methods?